# Having trouble storing objects into an arraylist using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, deserialization, objectinputstream

Ok i just changed my code to use true in the while loop.  Now when it is reading from the file i get a stream corrupted exception. cold this be because of the obin not being new.

private  class viewStudentListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                try{

```
                ArrayList<Student> students =  new ArrayList<Student>();
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Students.bin");
                ObjectInputStream obin = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                int id = Integer.parseInt(ID.getText());
                int count = 0;
                    while(true)
                    {   
                        try{
                        Student s = (Student) obin.readObject();
                        students.add(s);



                    }                       
                    catch(EOFException eofException){
                        break;
                    }

                    }
                    while (count < students.size())
                    {
                        if(students.get(count).equals(id))
                            {
                                fName.setText(students.get(count).getFirstName());
                                lName.setText(students.get(count).getLastName());
                            }
                        count++;
                    }


            }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

}
    }

**This is how the file is being written**

```
private class createNewStudentListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            Student s = new Student(enterFirstName.getText(), enterLastName.getText());
            File newStudent;
            newStudent = new File("Students.bin");
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("Students.bin", newStudent.exists());
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputFile = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
            objectOutputFile.writeObject(s);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The new student was added successfully");
            String id = Integer.toString(s.getID());
            IDNUM.setText(id);
            s = null;
            objectOutputFile.close();
        }
        catch (emptyString a)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception a) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your for loop is newer ending

Comment: doesnt the loop throw a end of file exception at the end?

Comment: You can probably save yourself a lot of trouble by simply serializing an ArrayList of Students or whatever it is, and later reading out the one serialized object.

Comment: How are you *writing* this file?

Answer (score 0):

`available() > 0` is not a valid test for end of stream. See the Javadoc.

The correct way to read your stream is via `while (true)` until `EOFException` is thrown.